# Is there a difference between the actual chip intended for Dual Channel vs Triple Channel

Tags: memory

Is there a difference between the actual chips intended for Dual Channel vs Triple Channel. I bought a set of triple channel memory but I'm only using 2 of the 3 chips. I'm getting the error "Display driver NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 197.45 stopped responding and has successfully recovered" There seems to be a TON of discussion on the web about this and some say it might be RAM related. [This](http://www.corsair.com/memory-3/xms-classic/ddr3-xms3/tr3x6g1600c8.html) is the ram I'm using.

Thanks

Comment: What NVidia Video Card, and drivers are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is completely unrelated.

That error message is related to your display driver crashing. You may want to try to upgrade the drivers if there is one available.

As for the memory, you may want to [read this answer I wrote](https://superuser.com/questions/83546/triple-vs-dual-channel-with-6-sticks-of-memory/83558#83558), it will give you some background information on dual/triple channel memory. Basically, it should not make a difference.

Comment: I tried drivers with no luck. Same for other folks with this error. But Thanks for your answer regarding the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the modules themselves. They are simply matched together and sold as a batch because they have been tested to perform similarly. Any combination of two of the modules will work just as well in a dual channel setup.

The difference is in the motherboard and CPU. Triple channel memory is limited to the socket 1366 X58 chipset motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in the dimms/drams.  run memtest86 to determine if your system is experiencing instabilities resulting from bad rams.